# Android Phonegap Database Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova

I create a database in a phonegap application (android) and populate it with test values.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("achievements", "1.0", "AchievementsDB", 1000);
    db.transaction(createTables, function(tx, error){
        console.log("Error Creating Tables: "+error);
    }, function(){
        console.log("Successfully created Tables in Database");
    });
```

here is the createTables function

```
function createTables(tx){
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Achievements (name unique, description)');  
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Achievements (name, description) VALUES (0, 1)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Achievements (name, description) VALUES ("good", "morning")');
```

}

the problem is. I always get the error Callback back. When I try a SELECT on the database it always says the retrieved data (the result data) is undefined. Also, I was wondering why I can´t access the data/data/mypackage/database folder of the phone (actually, DDMS just shows an empty data folder).

I really dont know anymore what´s the problem here I really googled and stackoverflowed a lot about this. Please give any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Phonegap makes the database here

> /data/data/package-name/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db

Secondly Where do you actually get the ErrorCallback in which query?

Comment: hey, I get the error Callback on the "createTables" query. I can access the 000..01.db file on an emulator, not on a phone, but thanks anyway. The more important thing is why I can´t work with my database.

Comment: First of all try checking one query at one time... I suppose in the Create Table query,you need to specify the types of data for column like tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Achievements (name unique text, description text)');

Comment: I test only the first Query now. The decleration of the types didnt help, but upvote for some tips. It first called successcallback on creating tables. The Result of a select of the test data was still undefined. The Emulator says on the first query "error processing SQL".

Comment: oops my bad.. It should be like this  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Achievements (name unique text, description text)');

Comment: can´t find the difference, sorry :) Sometimes it really calls the SuccessCB, but still, when I execute a SELECT on the data, the result data is "undefined"

Comment: oops my bad again.. It should be like this tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Achievements (name text unique, description text)');

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10219/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-dan)